# Curl receives expired cookies

Tags: firefox, curl, expired, cookie

Why does curl receive an expired cookie?

In a response to some url the server is sending a `302 Found` response and a cookie. In Firefox this cookie gets set seamlessly. Firebug says:

```
    Set-Cookie  somekookie=91b115e3d4a5889ed93e70a7ddb24957a1eb0e27cbcd96a3342a8064; expires=Sun, 24-Oct-2010 23:28:55 GMT; path=/; domain=.somedomain.ru
```

However when curl requests the same url, the cookie is expired, curl's output:

```
    * Added cookie somecookie="deleted" for domain somedomain.com, path /, expire 1224891945
    < Set-Cookie: somecookie=deleted; expires=Fri, 24-Oct-2008 23:45:45 GMT; path=/; domain=.somedomain.com
```

Why does the date appear to be so old and how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

`curl -L -b null somedomain.com`

-b turns on cookies, -L follows a location (302). 'null' is any empty/nonexistent file.

or perhaps storing the cookies:

`curl -b cookies -c cookies somedomain.com`

-c writes to a netscape-style cookies file.

Without any more information that's the best I can do. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Well, when curl does the request there's no Cookie set (unless you specify one), so the server is probably just saying: this is a new session, I'm gonna delete any cookie you might have for any of the sites on this domain just in case.

On the firefox one, is there a cookie *sent* with the request?